# How do i add swift view controller protocol delegate methods in objective c viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

swiftFile

```
@objc protocol loadFilesDelegate {
func filesDownloaded(responce : Bool)
}

class ClassDetailVC: UIViewController
```

Objective -C File

```
@interface SecondVC ()
{

}
```

How do i get delegate in secondVC (ObjC File)

Comment: wouldnt it be the same as obj-c? `@interface SecondVC () <loadFilesDelegate>`

Comment: You need to create a property of the delegate in _ClassDetailVC_. Then you'll access the delegate as _detail.delegate_.